# How to get min, seconds and milliseconds from datetime.now() in python?

Tags: python, datetime, time

```
>>> a = str(datetime.now())
>>> a
'2012-03-22 11:16:11.343000'
```

I need to get a string like that: `'16:11.34'`.

Should be as compact as possible.

Or should I use time() instead?
How do I get it?

Comment: You mean you want it truncated as `16:11.34`, or something else?

Comment: Yes, trancate or foramt or parse. I don't know.

Comment: @Marcin, I haven't tried anythong because I don't know what to try.

Comment: Maybe it should read *whathaveyouresearched* ...

Answer (score 58, accepted):

What about:

`datetime.now().strftime('%M:%S.%f')[:-4]`

I'm not sure what you mean by "Milliseconds only 2 digits", but this should keep it to 2 decimal places.  There may be a more elegant way by manipulating the strftime format string to cut down on the precision as well -- I'm not completely sure.

**EDIT**

If the `%f` modifier doesn't work for you, you can try something like:

```
now=datetime.now()
string_i_want=('%02d:%02d.%d'%(now.minute,now.second,now.microsecond))[:-4]
```

Again, I'm assuming you just want to truncate the precision.

Comment: '>>>datetime.now().strftime('%M:%S.%f')[:-4]'    Result: ''   Something is not correct.

Comment: `[:-4]` means "start at the beginning and exclude the last 4 characters".  For some reason, `%f` isn't working here and my final result is `36:31.f` truncated to `36:`.  @Prostak may also be getting a truncated result...

Comment: What is incorrect?  Does it raise an error?  I think the %f modifier was added in python 2.6 (although I'm not positive) -- what version of python are you using?

Comment: I am restricted to 2.4.3. When I am using `datetime.now().strftime('%M:%S.%f')[:-4]` I get `''`. If I use `datetime.now().strftime('%M:%S.f')[:-4]`, I get `'46:'`

Comment: Ahhh...I've added a solution that should work with older versions as well.

Comment: @mgilson, it works!, but is it possible to compress it to a single line?

Comment: @Prostak, I think that the best way to condense it would be to put it into a function ...  Alternatively, you could call "datetime.now()" everywhere "now" is seen in the above equation, but then you have 3 different times you're dealing with, (and the computational overhead of 3 separate function calls).

Comment: @mgilson, so `strftime()` doesn't allow the millisecond parameter? if not, it should be addressed by python community. ideally I would like to use something like that: `datetime.now().strftime('%M:%S.%s')`.......2 min later: I see, it was added in later version but not in 2.4.....

Comment: "%a %b %d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S:%f " = Day Short-Month date/month/year hour minute second millisecond

Answer (score 17):

This solution is very similar to that provided by @gdw2 , only that the string formatting is correctly done to match what you asked for - "Should be as compact as possible"

```
>>> import datetime
>>> a = datetime.datetime.now()
>>> "%s:%s.%s" % (a.minute, a.second, str(a.microsecond)[:2])
'31:45.57'
```

Comment: what about method `strftime()` .... I just can't figure out the parameter for milliseconds `datetime.now().strftime('%M:%S.??')`. maybe you know?

Comment: If you HAVE to use strftime then the solution from @mgilson seems like what you'd need to do, that is: datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%M:%S.%f")[:-4] to get the exact format that you asked for
   `>>>import datetime
    >>>datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%M:%S.%f")[:-4]
    '14:07.90'`

Comment: but i don't have to use `strftime()`......... it is just the one that provides one line solution

Comment: In that case, if you don't mind the three different function calls to datetime.now(), you could do `>>> "%s:%s.%s" % (datetime.datetime.now().minute, datetime.datetime.now().second, str(datetime.datetime.now().microsecond)[:2])`
`'21:51.16'` This does make calling datetime.now() redundant but I don't think there is a time difference in the three different function calls. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 4):

if you want your `datetime.now()` precise till the minute , you can use

```
datetime.strptime(datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M'), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
```

similarly for hour it will be

```
datetime.strptime(datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H'), '%Y-%m-%d %H')
```

It is kind of a hack, if someone has a better solution, I am all ears

Answer (score 3):

Another similar solution:

```
>>> a=datetime.now()
>>> "%s:%s.%s" % (a.hour, a.minute, a.microsecond)
'14:28.971209'
```

Yes, I know I didn't get the string formatting perfect.

Comment: what about method `strftime()` .... I just can't figure out the parameter for milliseconds `datetime.now().strftime('%M:%S.??')`. maybe you know?

Comment: I would use `%d` instead of `%s` because you are dealing with integer values (**d**igits).

Answer (score 3):

```
import datetime from datetime

now = datetime.now()

print "%0.2d:%0.2d:%0.2d" % (now.hour, now.minute, now.second)
```

You can do the same with day & month etc.

Answer (score 0):

time.second helps a lot put that at the top of your python.

Answer (score 0):

To the min, seconds and milliseconds, you can first import `datetime`.
Then you define a object with the `datetime.datetime.now()`.
Then you can as that object for min, seconds and milliseconds, bu using the sub function of the class.

```py
import datetime
now = datetime.datetime.now()
print (now.year)
print (now.month)
print (now.day)
print (now.hour)
print (now.minute)
print (now.second)
print (now.microsecond)
```

You can read more about her https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.year

Answer (score -2):

Sorry to open an old thread but I'm posting just in case it helps someone. This seems to be the easiest way to do this in Python 3.

```
from datetime import datetime

Date = str(datetime.now())[:10]
Hour = str(datetime.now())[11:13]
Minute = str(datetime.now())[14:16]
Second = str(datetime.now())[17:19]
Millisecond = str(datetime.now())[20:]
```

If you need the values as a number just cast them as an int e.g

```
Hour = int(str(datetime.now())[11:13])
```

Comment: This not a good idea. You're not using the methods that the library offers - see other answers.

If they ever change the format so that the spaces are shifted, you'll end up with with hardcoded string positions burried somewhere deep in your code which at best will raise an error, at worst will render computations incorrect and potentially hard to debug. Never hardcode positions like that if you can avoid it, which you can here.